# R Optimize model parameters

Tags: r, optimization

I understand how to use "optim" to fit a least squares regression line. However, that requires a set of data (2 variables).

Now, I have a model (with model parameters) and a set of "observed data". I would like to optimise the model parameters via minimisation of RSS/RMSE.

I do not know how to perform this through "optim". Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

---

- I have attached an example. The model input is only in the first timestep because this is some kind of autoregressive model:

[image: Model]

> and  H[i] = H[i-1] x 0.8

where *Y* is the modelled value for timestep i;
*P* is the model input;
*H*i-1, *A* and *S* are the model parameters to be optimised.
For i=(1-16), what are the optimum model parameters?

Data:

```
i   P   obs
1   42  5.208
2   0   3.119
3   0   2.642
4   0   2.280
5   0   1.995
6   0   1.899
7   0   1.893
8   0   1.766
9   0   1.577
10  0   1.523
11  0   1.494
12  0   1.470
13  0   1.497
14  0   1.465
15  0   1.377
16  0   1.337
```

where i is the timestep; P is the model input; "obs" is the observed values.

Comment: A = S = 0, H[i-1] = Y[i] - P[i] gives a perfect fit.

Comment: There is a range of values (0.001-0.9) for each parameter. Parameters cannot be zero. This is just a simplified example.
I need to know how to do this through R either via optim or some other method.

Comment: You need another equation describing something about Hi. Otherwise, for any value of A and S you can find a suitable H. It becomes indeterminate

Comment: @Rohit Thank you for pointing that out. I have amended the question. Added an additional equation. H[i] = H[i-1] x 0.8

Comment: If you write H[i] in terms of H0, It becomes a non-linear equation because of the `AxH0` term. I think you can try an iterative approach: First assume some value for H0, and solve for A,S. Then use the estimates of A,S to solve for H0. And then iterate till the values converge.